# How to print a half pyramid in javascript

Tags: javascript

The code works but I don't want the inner for loop to take me to the new line.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    console.log('*');
  }
  console.log();
}
console.log('-----------------');
```

Comment: Instead of logging directly, construct a string inside the inner loop and print it after the loop completes.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: This code works?

Comment: Guys, the question seems rather clear. At the moment the code is printing a newline after each `'*'` and OP doesn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` will automatically break the line. Concatenate to a string instead of a log. Log at the end.

```js
let str = '';

for(i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       str += '*';
    }
    str += '\n';
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way, with the help of a string variable:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var str = '';
  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    str+='*';
  }
  console.log(str);
}
console.log('-----------------');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print at the page, use like below

```
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let j=0;
      do{document.write("*");j++;}while(j < i)
      document.write("<br/>")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "";

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    string += '*';
    console.log(string);
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the line with the `console.log` you can also controle the space between * with `output+='*' + " ";`

```js
function pyramid() {
    var total = 5;
    var output="";
    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            output+='*' + " ";
        }
        console.log(output);
        output="";
    }
}  

pyramid()
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions: if you declare `output` inside the outer loop, you don't need to reset it after each cycle. Also, I see no indication OP wants a space after each `'*'`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i know it was just a suggestion , i just tried  a diffrent aproach from the other answear

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of second for loop as follows:

```js
 var str = '';
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    str +=Array(i).join("*");
    str +='\n';
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this "exercise" in JavaScript:

```
let width = ""
while(width.length < 6) console.log(width += `#` );
```

Basically, we create a string (width) and increment its value using the while loop till we hit a restriction.

I found the more typical method "bulky"(?)...plus there's the issue of not getting the exact picture of a half pyramid.

```
let i,j 

for (i= 0; i < 6; i++){

    for (j = 0; j<=i; j++){
        console.log("#")
    }
    console.log("\n")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function pyramid(n){   
    let result = "";    
    for(let i=0; i<=n; i++){  
        result += "*".repeat(i);  
        result += "\n"  
    }   
    return result;   
}
console.log(pyramid(5));
//OutPut
*
**
***
****
*****
```

As we need n number of pyramid structure with '' / '#' / any symbol. by using above code we can achieve. Here you can see we just created a function called pyramid with one parameter 'n'. and inside function we declare a variable 'result'. So inside for loop the length of 'i' is "<=n" and also you can use "repeat() method to print '' 'i' times. So if you call that function like console.log(pyramid(5)); You can able to see your Answer as expected..

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: As we need n  number of pyramid structure with '*' / '#' / any symbol. by using above code we can achieve.  Here you can see we just created a function called pyramid with one parameter 'n'. and inside function we declare a variable 'result'. So inside for loop the length of 'i' is "<=n" and also you can use "repeat() method to print '*' 'i' times. So if you call that function like console.log(pyramid(5)); You can able to see your Answer as expected..

Comment: Please **edit** your answer instead of adding an explanation in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

shortest code:

```js
console.log('*\n**\n***\n****\n*****');
```

Comment: aww come on ... it's valid!! :p